# BlueprintCallable functions not appearing in Blueprint - UE5

Tags: blueprints, unreal-5

Only just started working with Unreal Engine 5 and I have an issue were my BlueprintCallable functions are not appearing/callable in the blueprint. I dont have the same issue with Unreal Engine 4.

[image]

[image]

Unchecking/Checking "Context Sensitive" does nothing. I have build the visual studio code in development/deployment/editor, compiled UE and restarted editor, restarted visual studio without any luck. What am I missing for these functions to be available in my blueprint?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Untitled]

Uncheck Live coding if It is checked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You have to Recompile and reload C++ code by hitting the Recompile button at the bottom of the editor:

[image: Compile]

Comment: i spend more than 5hours and 100 youtube Tutorial no one mention that. Thanks you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you making a Blueprint Function Library?
If so make sure you declare your functions as static members.

```
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
static void OpenLobby();
```

Comment: Discovered a few days ago, its a thing with UE5 at the moment were any code I add in c++, blueprints are not picking up the updates/changes even after building. So I have to close my UE editor -> build in c++ -> delete Binaries, Saved and Intermediate folders -> Generate Visual Studio files. Only then are the changes picked up by UE Editor. Annoying that I have to do this every time I change my code in c++. Dont have this issue if I am on UE4 project on same machine.

Comment: @LavsTo Really annoying